# Is there a threshold when emailing a group via workflow?

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, groups

I created 2 groups in SharePoint 2010.  One has approximately 20 users and the other has 1600 users. I created a workflow that uses Group 1 (20 users) in the BCC field to send an email to this group.  It works fine.  When I edit the workflow to send the email to the larger group (same permissions), it does not send the email.  Is there a threshold for how many members it may email?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of a limit for emails in workflows.  Does the workflow fire correctly without error?  If so I would check your mail server to see if it received the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit officially suggested by Microsoft on the number of Email recipients. (Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1cb49ae8-16c3-4102-8059-cecc0cda6925/number-of-participants-in-sp2010-ootb-workflow?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious))

But, still if the recipients have not received the email. You may want to look for following,

1. Whether none of the receipient received the mail or its just few of
   them.
2. They may want to check the Junk folder :)
3. There could be firewall issues(blocking the mails).
4. It could be the mail server itself(unable to handle bulk email
   sending).

Comment: There is a threshold on the Exchange box.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Good to see that it helped you.